# How can I improve my dataset , layers and hyperparameters to achieve my goal?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, hyperparameters

Hi to all the community,
I'm currently working on a Neural Network to provide some simulation about the topic I'm developing for my graduation thesis in biomedical engineering and I'm currently facing some issues regarding a poor performance of my network.This is my first time using python, keras, tensorflow and in machine learning in general.

Data:

Basically, I want to predict a vector that contains the values of the conductivity in a circular mesh composed of N frames. I've previously generated 10000 meshes, each with a circular artifact in a random position. This artifact involves a change in the conductivity. The background conductivity is set to 1, in the center of the artifact is 100, in the boundary of the artifact ~50. I've simulated an injection of current at the boundary of my mesh, reading for each mesh 208 voltages obtained from 16 electrodes placed at the boundary. My aim is to develop a NN that, given an array of (208) voltages, can predict the vector of conductivity, that I'll elaborate in Matlab  to reconstruct the predicted image.
So i have:
10k arrays of 208 voltages, with range [10^(-2),10^(-4)]
10k arrays of N conductivities , ranging from 1 to 100.
The only pre processing that I've done is a normalization between [1,-1] for the voltages, and a restriction to [1-50-100] for the conductivity, then a normalization [1,-1] .

This is the code i'm actually running to do my tests.

```
inp = pd.read_csv (r' ........input.csv',header = None) 
out = pd.read_csv (r'........output.csv',header = None) 

X, Y = inp.values, out.values

print(X.shape)
print(Y.shape)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.30, 
random_state=0)
x_validate, x_test, y_validate, y_test = train_test_split(x_test, y_test, 
test_size=0.5, random_state=0)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(416, input_dim=208, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(585, activation='tanh'))

sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=1)
model.compile(loss=losses.mean_squared_error, optimizer=sgd, metrics= 
['accuracy', 'acc', 'mse'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1000, batch_size=128, validation_data= 
(x_validate, y_validate))
```

I've tried various activation for both dense layers : relu, tanh, linear, in all combinations possible. Various learning rates and data pre processing (now i'm stuck with the one i've described up there). By the way the best accuracy i'm getting is 0.1 , a mse of 0.02/0.03. Where i should start to work to optimize the structure of the network to achieve better result? I'm sure that i'm failing in something upstream, and i would be immensely grateful if someone can just give me some tips, some food for though so i can move in the right direction.
I'm sorry for the mistakes in the writing but english is not my main language.

Edit:

```py
>>> print(model.summary())
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 416)               86944
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 585)               243945
=================================================================
Total params: 330,889
Trainable params: 330,889
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

```
>>> print(model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0))
[0.005556682635098696, 0.07133333336313566, 0.07133333336313566, 0.005556682635098696]
```

Comment: Would you explain how your data looks like? or `print( X.shape)` or and `print( Y.shape)`

Comment: Sure. My data is stored in 2 matrix on 2  csv files.Input : 10000x208 , output 10000x585. Each row is a different case.

Comment: Can you `print(model.summary())` or `print(model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=0))`?

Comment: I edited the first post

Comment: you might to finetune it by changing learning rate but as long as your loss plot is satisfying and you don't have overfit/underfit and the other hand your MSE is low enough you could just optimize results by using callback techniques like early stopping to improve a bit your training process. have you tried other `optimizer=adam` ?

Answer (score 1):

In machine learning, hyperparameter optimization or tuning is the problem of choosing a set of optimal hyperparameters for a learning algorithm and **it's really traditional and all data scientists face this** when tuning their models.

That said, there are many great tools for all sorts of scenarios which can be used to aid you in this process:

For tensorflow I recommend reading: https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/r2/hyperparameter_tuning_with_hparams

For keras: https://towardsdatascience.com/hyperparameter-optimization-with-keras-b82e6364ca53

And of course, there are many more and searching with the right terms of hyperparameters tuning/optimization you can find great resources online.